# SSIS: Connect Oracle DB as Source and MS SQL Server as target

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have to extract data from oracle database (which is in remote location) and then store the data to MS SQL Server Database using SSIS.
I am new to SSIS so I am unaware of what are the softwares needs to be installed and where I have to start.

Oracle Database (12c) and MS SQL Server (2012) is in remote location.

I tried the following but I am unlucky.

Using SSMS import / Export wizard. I tried to select oracle DB as my source but I end up with the below error

```
TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

The operation could not be completed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed. (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I googled and tried to install oracle client but not working.

Please give me a proper direction from where I have to start.

Comment: use `DataFlowTask` and defined you OLEDB Source and Destination to move data from source to destination.

Comment: How to select Remote Oracle Database Server as OLEDB Source. What are the softwares needs to be installed to select oracle db as source.

Comment: use this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-adding-data-flow-to-your-package/)

Comment: Thanks but the article does not provide how to link oracle db as data source